# Find sum students inside document of university

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How calculate total number of students in each university from document? Try lookup and group.

- University definded by name. There are many names.

#This the collection:

```js
db.universities.insert([
{
  country : 'Spain',
  city : 'Salamanca',
  name : 'USAL',
  location : {
    type : 'Point',
    coordinates : [ -5.6722512,17, 40.9607792 ]
  },
  students : [
    { year : 2014, number : 24774 },
    { year : 2015, number : 23166 },
    { year : 2016, number : 21913 },
    { year : 2017, number : 21715 }
  ]
},
{
  country : 'Spain',
  city : 'Salamanca',
  name : 'UPSA',
  location : {
    type : 'Point',
    coordinates : [ -5.6691191,17, 40.9631732 ]
  },
  students : [
    { year : 2014, number : 4788 },
    { year : 2015, number : 4821 },
    { year : 2016, number : 6550 },
    { year : 2017, number : 6125 }
  ]
}
])
```

[My code]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYUDi.png

Comment: please add details of desired outputs and describe what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Linor!

As written in the comments, it is better if you will explain what is your desired outputs. If all you want is to sum the number of student per each document, you can use a basic query, like:

```
db.collection.find({}, {total: {$sum: "$students.number"}, name: 1})
```

That will return it, as you can see on the mongodb [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cyHy2VpYJ01). The first par of the query is the matching part, choosing which documents to use (in your case, with no further data, all of them). The second part is the projection, meaning the formatting of the data. Here we use `$sum` in order to sum the number of students fir each document.

Comment: Is it working for you?